# Find the relation between these numbers

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

I've just joined and wanted to contribute a bit myself so here are 3 puzzles my friend made to test me, first two I've solved but third one stomped me, see if you can solve it yourself!

**First one** -

Describe the relation between 
X (left number) and Y (right number):

1,1 = 0

1,3 = -8

1,6 = -35

1,28 = -783

2,2 = ?

Good job if you solved it but it's going to get harder

**Second one** -

Again same rules as the first one, however this time there is one parameter involved in the equation that describes the relation:

3,6 = 21

4,14 = 38

7,15 = 78

2,23 = 31

1,7 = ?

Okay this one was harder in my opinion, good job if you solved it!
Next one is ALOT harder in my opinion but then again i know there are some brilliant folks here

**Third one** -

Same rules as the first two however this time there are two parameters involved in the equation:

1,14 = 4

3,16 = 192

3,26 = 132

7,10 = 1428

1,1 = ?

Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third one

> $30$

Since

> $32x^2-2xy = z$

Comment: Exactly! Very impressive, keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

Puzzle one:

> 0 - the difference between the two numbers multiplied by the sum of the two numbers - (2-2)*(2+2)=0

Puzzle two (solved by *Jeremy Dover*):

> 10 - the first squared plus twice the first plus the second

Comment: It could equally be rot13(zvahf gjb, ol fhogenpgvat gur fdhner bs gur frpbaq sebz gur svefg) - as with many sequence questions, this does not have a unique answer...

Comment: The second is: rot13(gur svefg fdhnerq cyhf gjvpr gur svefg cyhf gur frpbaq), or as Stiv points out, any of an infinite number of other possibilities.

Comment: Good on you for giving it a try, however your answer does not account for the minuses, Yes I'm aware that there can be multiple different answers however I'm asking for the shortest most simplified equation to describe each one, I'm pretty sure there is only one possiblity of such however feel free to prove me wrong..

Comment: Second answer by Jeremy is Correct (:

Comment: @Barsloai I tested my equation for 1 and it works...

Comment: Oh OK I didn't understand that in you're answered you mentioned minus, I thought it was just a dash to distinguish, either way there is simpler solution, good job though!

Answer (score 1):

Answer of the first puzzle should be

> -2

Rule:

> X-Y*Y
>  1-1*1=0
>  1-9=-8
>  1-36=-35
>  1-28*28=-783

Then

> 2-4=-2

Comment: Hi Dharmendra - I agree; this is what I wrote in my comment on Daniil's answer. In case you don't know, on Puzzling we often hide comments that might spoil the puzzle for others by using rot-13 (shifting each letter in the alphabet by 13 characters). You can decode these easily by copy-pasting the coded text and using [this site](https://rot13.com/) - test it out; if you linger longer on this site you'll definitely need it! :)

Comment: Good job, and yea this what I was having in mind too, definitely simpler than Daniil's solution